# filtering dynamically a table In Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, filter, excel-formula, dynamic

Is there a way to have a dynamic array formula that gives the solution as per cells A11:B12 out of the Table A1:B6.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4shs.png)

meaning that if a customer C would be added with product V, it would dynamically add a line [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVxdt.png)
I would imagine that in A11 there would be something like **UNIQUE(Table1[Client])**?? But how to get with a Dynamic Array formula the products in column B?

Thank you for your help

I tried the filter function couple with xmatch, but could not make it to run due to the dynamic nature of the lookup range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the formula as shown below,

[image]

• Formula used in cell `A10`

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(Table23[Client]),BYROW(UNIQUE(Table23[Client]),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(",",,REPT(Table23[Product],x=Table23[Client])))))
```

---

You can wrap the whole within a `LET()` to make it more readable, like as below,

[image]

• Formula used in cell `A10`

```
=LET(_client,UNIQUE(Table23[Client]),
HSTACK(_client,BYROW(_client,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(",",,REPT(Table23[Product],x=Table23[Client]))))))
```

---

You can use a `FILTER()` function in place of `REPT()`

[image]

• Formula used in cell `A10`

```
=LET(_client,UNIQUE(Table23[Client]),
HSTACK(_client,BYROW(_client,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(Table23[Product],x=Table23[Client]))))))
```

---

You can also try in this way as well,

[image]

• Formula used in cell `A9`

```
=DROP(IFERROR(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(Table23[Client]),LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,HSTACK(b,TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTER(Table23[Product],Table23[Client]=b)))))),""),1)
```

Comment: Holly Guacamole!! You nailed it, VERY IMPRESSIVE. Thank you so much.

Comment: @JéromeAstier glad to know it worked for you =)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (a bit more verbose), you could try:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=REDUCE(Table1[#Headers],UNIQUE(Table1[Client]),LAMBDA(a,b,VSTACK(a,HSTACK(b,TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(Table1[Product],Table1[Client]=b))))))
```